x509: certificate signed by unknown authority Hyperledger Fabric
I am trying to create a new peer which will be running in a different host machine. As I have the express js server with the react in my main host, all works fine with using the admin and client certs before i register the new peer. After the peer is registered and running, all the certs giving error saying like below.
2024-11-30 03:39:29.297 UTC 0043 WARN [endorser] Validate -> access denied channel=mychannel txID=d9ae6785 error="the supplied identity is not valid: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of \"x509: ECDSA verification failure\" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate \"ca.org1.example.com\")" errorVerbose="x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of \"x509: ECDSA verification failure\" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate \"ca.org1.example.com\")\nthe supplied identity is not valid" identity="(mspid=Org1MSP subject=CN=PATIENT_1,OU=org1+OU=client+OU=patient,O=Hyperledger,ST=North Carolina,C=US issuer=CN=ca.org1.example.com,O=org1.example.com,L=Durham,ST=North Carolina,C=US serialnumber=730594218695751457221358860858176473267678034244)"
2024-11-30 03:39:29.297 UTC 0044 WARN [endorser] ProcessProposal -> Failed to preProcess proposal error="error validating proposal: access denied: channel [mychannel] creator org unknown, creator is malformed"

point to note would be it works fine with admin certs, I am running my peers in docker containers.
peer0
 peer0.org1.example.com:
container_name: peer0.org1.example.com
image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest
labels:
  service: hyperledger-fabric
environment:
  - FABRIC_CFG_PATH=/etc/hyperledger/peercfg
  - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=INFO
  #- FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=DEBUG
  - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
  - CORE_PEER_PROFILE_ENABLED=false
  - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.crt
  - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.key
  - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/ca.crt
  # Peer specific variables
  - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.org1.example.com
  - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
  - CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7051
  - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODEADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7052
  - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7052
  - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
  - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
  - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_USELEADERELECTION=false
  - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ORGLEADER=true
  - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
  - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
  - CORE_OPERATIONS_LISTENADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:9444
  - CORE_METRICS_PROVIDER=prometheus
  - CHAINCODE_AS_A_SERVICE_BUILDER_CONFIG={"peername":"peer0org1"}
  - CORE_CHAINCODE_EXECUTETIMEOUT=300s
volumes:
  - ../organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com:/etc/hyperledger/fabric
  - peer0.org1.example.com:/var/hyperledger/production
working_dir: /root
command: peer node start
ports:
  - 7051:7051
  - 9444:9444
networks:
  - test

new peer i am running some automation to register and enroll
    #!/bin/bash

# Set the root directory to the raspberry-pi folder
ROOTDIR=$(cd "$(dirname "$0")" && pwd)
export PATH=${ROOTDIR}/bin:$PATH
export FABRIC_CFG_PATH=${ROOTDIR}/config

# Automatically detect the laptop's IP address
laptop_ip=$(hostname -I | awk '{print $1}')
echo "Detected laptop IP: $laptop_ip"

# Get Raspberry Pi details from the user
read -p "Enter Raspberry Pi IP: " pi_ip
read -p "Enter SSH username for Raspberry Pi: " ssh_user
read -p "Enter PATIENT_ID for the patient: " patient_id

# Check if the CA container exists and is running
container_name=$(docker ps --filter "name=ca_org1" --format "{{.Names}}")
if [ -z "$container_name" ]; then
    echo "Error: No CA container named 'ca_org1' found. Ensure it is running."
    exit 1
fi

# Check if the peer container exists and is running
container_peer=$(docker ps --filter "name=peer0.org1.example.com" --format "{{.Names}}")
if [ -z "$container_peer" ]; then
    echo "Error: No container named 'peer0.org1.example.com' found. Ensure it is running."
    exit 1
fi

# Delete old certificates to ensure new ones are generated
echo "Deleting old CA certificates inside the Docker container..."
docker exec $container_name sh -c "rm -rf /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server/*.pem"

# Modify CA configuration inside Docker to add SAN for IPs
echo "Modifying CA configuration inside the Docker container..."
docker exec $container_name sh -c "
  sed -i '/hosts:/a \ \ \ \ - $laptop_ip' /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server/fabric-ca-server-config.yaml
  cat /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server/fabric-ca-server-config.yaml
"
# Restart the CA server to apply the new configuration
echo "Restarting the CA server..."
docker restart ${container_name}

# Add a delay to ensure the certificate is available
echo "Waiting for CA server to generate the certificate..."
sleep 5

echo "Copying CA certificate from Docker container to host..."
if ! docker cp ${container_name}:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server/ca-cert.pem ./ca-cert.pem; then
    echo "docker cp failed. Using fallback with docker exec..."
    docker exec ${container_name} cat /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server/ca-cert.pem > ./ca-cert.pem
fi

if [ ! -f ./ca-cert.pem ]; then
    echo "Error: Failed to copy CA certificate from the container."
    exit 1
fi

# Enroll the admin user on the CA server
echo "Enrolling admin user..."
docker exec $container_name fabric-ca-client enroll \
  -u https://admin:adminpw@localhost:7054 --caname ca-org1 \
  --tls.certfiles /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server/ca-cert.pem \
  --enrollment.profile tls 

# Determine the next available peer index
peer_index=0
while docker exec $container_name fabric-ca-client identity list --id "peer${peer_index}" \
  --tls.certfiles /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server/ca-cert.pem 2>&1 | grep -q "Name:"; do
    echo "Found existing peer${peer_index}. Incrementing index..."
    peer_index=$((peer_index + 1))
done

peer_name="peer${peer_index}"
echo "Next peer to be registered: ${peer_name}"

# Register the new peer with the CA server
echo "Registering ${peer_name} with CA server..."
if ! docker exec $container_name fabric-ca-client register \
  --caname ca-org1 \
  --id.name "${peer_name}" --id.secret peerpw --id.type peer \
  --tls.certfiles ./ca-cert.pem; then
    echo "Error: Failed to register ${peer_name} with the CA server."
    exit 1
fi

# Create the channel if it doesn't exist
if [ ! -f ../first-network/channel-artifacts/mychannel.block ]; then
    echo "Creating channel..."
    peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c mychannel -f ../first-network/channel-artifacts/mychannel.tx
else
    echo "Channel already exists. Skipping channel creation."
fi

# Setup directories and transfer files on Raspberry Pi
echo "Setting up directories on Raspberry Pi..."
ssh $ssh_user@$pi_ip <<EOF
  mkdir -p ~/remote-monitoring/{bin,builders,config,chaincode,scripts,tls,channel-artifacts,msp,tlsca}
  mkdir -p ~/remote-monitoring/msp/Admin@org1.example.com
EOF

# Transfer necessary files to the Raspberry Pi
echo "Transferring files to Raspberry Pi..."
scp -r ./bin ./builders ./config ./config ca-cert.pem \
    $ssh_user@$pi_ip:~/remote-monitoring/
scp ../first-network/channel-artifacts/mychannel.block \
    $ssh_user@$pi_ip:~/remote-monitoring/channel-artifacts/
scp ./docker-compose-peer.yaml \
    $ssh_user@$pi_ip:~/remote-monitoring/
scp ../first-network/patient.tar.gz \
    $ssh_user@$pi_ip:~/remote-monitoring/chaincode/
scp -r ../first-network/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/msp/* \
    $ssh_user@$pi_ip:~/remote-monitoring/msp/
scp ./server.js \
    $ssh_user@$pi_ip:~/server/
scp -r ../first-network/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/tlsca \
    $ssh_user@$pi_ip:~/remote-monitoring/

# Create the .env file on Raspberry Pi with the peer index
ssh $ssh_user@$pi_ip <<EOF
echo "CA_SERVER_IP=${laptop_ip}" > ~/remote-monitoring/.env
echo "PEER_INDEX=${peer_index}" >> ~/remote-monitoring/.env
rm ~/server/.env
echo "PATIENT_ID=${patient_id}" >> ~/server/.env
EOF

# Create the network.sh script on the Raspberry Pi
ssh $ssh_user@$pi_ip <<EOF
  chmod +x ~/remote-monitoring/bin/*

  cat > ~/remote-monitoring/scripts/network.sh << 'END_OF_NETWORK_SCRIPT'
#!/bin/bash

docker stop \$(docker ps -a)
docker rm -fv \$(docker ps -aq)

raspberry_ip=\$(hostname -I | awk '{print \$1}')
echo "Registering \${raspberry_ip} "

# Load variables from .env file
if [ ! -f ~/remote-monitoring/.env ]; then
    echo "Error: .env file not found."
    exit 1
fi

export CA_SERVER_IP=\$(grep -oP '(?<=CA_SERVER_IP=)\S+' ~/remote-monitoring/.env)
peer_index=\$(grep -oP '(?<=PEER_INDEX=)\S+' ~/remote-monitoring/.env)

peer_id="peer\${peer_index}"  # Identity used during registration
peer_name="peer\${peer_index}.org1.example.com"
container_name="\${peer_name}"
api_key=\$(openssl rand -hex 16)

echo "PEER_NAME=\${peer_name}" >> ~/server/.env
echo "API_KEY=\${api_key}" >> ~/server/.env

echo "Setting up \${peer_name}..."

export PATH=~/remote-monitoring/bin:\$PATH
export FABRIC_CFG_PATH=~/remote-monitoring/config
export FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_HOME=~/remote-monitoring/msp/\${peer_name}

if [ -z "\$CA_SERVER_IP" ]; then
    echo "Error: CA_SERVER_IP is not set in the .env file."
    exit 1
fi
  
echo "Enrolling \${peer_name} with CA server at \${CA_SERVER_IP}..."
fabric-ca-client enroll -u "https://\${peer_id}:peerpw@\${CA_SERVER_IP}:7054" \
  --caname ca-org1 \
  --tls.certfiles ~/remote-monitoring/ca-cert.pem \
  -M ~/remote-monitoring/msp/\${peer_name} \
  --csr.hosts "\${peer_name},\${CA_SERVER_IP},\${raspberry_ip},localhost"

CA_SERVER_IP_DASH="\${CA_SERVER_IP//./-}"

# Create the config.yaml file
cat > ~/remote-monitoring/msp/\${peer_name}/config.yaml <<END_CONFIG
NodeOUs:
  Enable: true
  ClientOUIdentifier:
    Certificate: cacerts/\${CA_SERVER_IP_DASH}-7054-ca-org1.pem
    OrganizationalUnitIdentifier: client
  PeerOUIdentifier:
    Certificate: cacerts/\${CA_SERVER_IP_DASH}-7054-ca-org1.pem
    OrganizationalUnitIdentifier: peer
  AdminOUIdentifier:
    Certificate: cacerts/\${CA_SERVER_IP_DASH}-7054-ca-org1.pem
    OrganizationalUnitIdentifier: admin
  OrdererOUIdentifier:
    Certificate: cacerts/\${CA_SERVER_IP_DASH}-7054-ca-org1.pem
    OrganizationalUnitIdentifier: orderer
END_CONFIG

# Second enrollment specifically for TLS
fabric-ca-client enroll -u "https://\${peer_id}:peerpw@\${CA_SERVER_IP}:7054" \
  --caname ca-org1 \
  --tls.certfiles ~/remote-monitoring/ca-cert.pem \
  -M ~/remote-monitoring/msp/\${peer_name}/tls \
  --enrollment.profile tls \
  --csr.hosts "\${peer_name},\${CA_SERVER_IP},\${raspberry_ip},localhost"

# Copy TLS materials to required locations with specific names
cp ~/remote-monitoring/msp/\${peer_name}/tls/tlscacerts/* ~/remote-monitoring/msp/\${peer_name}/tls/ca.crt
cp ~/remote-monitoring/msp/\${peer_name}/tls/signcerts/* ~/remote-monitoring/msp/\${peer_name}/tls/server.crt
cp ~/remote-monitoring/msp/\${peer_name}/tls/keystore/* ~/remote-monitoring/msp/\${peer_name}/tls/server.key

# Copy TLS materials to required locations with specific names
cp ~/remote-monitoring/msp/\${peer_name}/tls/tlscacerts/* ~/remote-monitoring/tls/ca.crt
cp ~/remote-monitoring/msp/\${peer_name}/tls/signcerts/* ~/remote-monitoring/tls/server.crt
cp ~/remote-monitoring/msp/\${peer_name}/tls/keystore/* ~/remote-monitoring/tls/server.key

# Ensure required Docker image is available
required_image="hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest"
echo "Checking for required Docker image: \$required_image"

if ! docker image inspect "\$required_image" &> /dev/null; then
    echo "Required image \$required_image not found. Pulling..."
    docker pull "\$required_image" || { echo "Failed to pull \$required_image"; exit 1; }
else
    echo "Image \$required_image already exists."
fi

echo "Starting \${peer_name} using Docker Compose..."
PEER_NAME=\${peer_name} RASPBERRY_IP=\${raspberry_ip} SERVER_IP=\${CA_SERVER_IP} docker-compose -f ~/remote-monitoring/docker-compose-peer.yaml up -d || { echo "Failed to start \${peer_name}"; exit 1; }

sleep 10

echo "Joining \${peer_name} to the channel..."
docker exec \${container_name} peer channel join -b /remote-monitoring/channel-artifacts/mychannel.block

#Install chaincode on the peer
echo "Installing chaincode..."
docker exec \${container_name} peer lifecycle chaincode install /remote-monitoring/chaincode/patient.tar.gz

EOF

# Execute the network setup on the Raspberry Pi
echo "Executing network setup on Raspberry Pi..."
ssh $ssh_user@$pi_ip "bash ~/remote-monitoring/scripts/network.sh"

echo "Peer${peer_index} setup complete!"

docker compose for the new peer
version: '2'
services:
  peer:
    container_name: ${PEER_NAME}
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest
    environment:
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=DEBUG
      - CORE_PEER_ID=${PEER_NAME}
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=${PEER_NAME}:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7051
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODEADDRESS=${PEER_NAME}:7052
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7052
      - CORE_CHAINCODE_BUILDER=hyperledger/fabric-nodeenv:latest
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
      - FABRIC_CFG_PATH=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/config
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp/${PEER_NAME}/tls/server.crt
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp/${PEER_NAME}/tls/server.key
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp/${PEER_NAME}/tls/ca.crt

      # CouchDB settings
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_STATEDATABASE=CouchDB
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=couchdb:5984
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME=admin
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD=adminpw

      # Gossip settings
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_USELEADERELECTION=false
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ORGLEADER=true
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=${PEER_NAME}:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=192.168.1.81:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_SKIPHANDSHAKE=false

      # Orderer settings
      - ORDERER_URL=${SERVER_IP}:7050  # Using IP instead of hostname

    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - $HOME/remote-monitoring:/etc/hyperledger/fabric
      - $HOME/remote-monitoring:/remote-monitoring
      - $HOME/remote-monitoring/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp

    command: peer node start
    ports:
      - 7051:7051
      - 7052:7052
    depends_on:
      - couchdb
    networks:
      - test
    extra_hosts:
      - "orderer.example.com:${SERVER_IP}"
      - "peer0.org1.example.com:${SERVER_IP}"
      - "peer0.org2.example.com:${SERVER_IP}"

  couchdb:
    container_name: couchdb
    image: couchdb:3.3.3
    environment:
      - COUCHDB_USER=admin
      - COUCHDB_PASSWORD=adminpw
    ports:
      - 5984:5984
    networks:
      - test

networks:
  test:
    name: fabric_test

